# add_filter ( 'media_send_to_editor', ...) does not work on wp 3.5

Tags: media-settings

I have a problem with this -probably- abandoned plugin:

```
    <?php
/*
Plugin Name: RV Embed PDF
Description: When you upload PDF and insert a link to it with the Add Media button, it     will be automatically embedded in the page using Google Docs Viewer.
Author: Rong Vang Media
Author URI: http://www.rongvang.cz
Version: 1.0
*/
function rv_embedpdf($in){
$out = "";
if(preg_match("/href='(.*?\\.pdf)'/", $in, $matches)){
    $out .= '<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url='.$matches[1].'&embedded=true" style="width:100%; height:500px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>';
}

$out .= $in;

return $out;
}
add_filter ( 'media_send_to_editor', 'rv_embedpdf' );
```

can anybody help me to make it compatible with wp 3.5?

Answer (score 1):

`'media_send_to_editor` works fine in WordPress 3.5. I did not test the above code but you don't need to `preg_match` for *.pdf* when WordPress supports `post_mime_type == 'application/pdf;`

This should work better: https://gist.github.com/2176359
Just change the HTML parameters to your needs. I also advise to embed it directly as an `<iframe>`, native .pdf iframe browser support is better than sending it through *docs.google.com*.

Comment: [plugin author] Thanks, hotfix based on Wyck's help and linked plugin.
Will update the plugin soon, thanks for suggestion. http://wordpress.org/support/topic/rv-embed-pdf-does-not-work-on-v-35?replies=2#post-3656189